# removing bold characters from artwitz-fonts drift in urxvt

Tags: linux, fonts, urxvt

just switched my urxvt font to artwtiz-fonts drift, is there any way i can stop bold characters from displaying, they hurt my eyes?

the line in ~/.Xdefaults is: urxvt*font:xft:drift:pixelsize=12

scrot:

http://imgbox.com/acqBZ50R

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the bold font to a non-bold variant.

[e.g](http://wiki.afterstep.org/index.php?title=Rxvt-Unicode_Configuration_Tutorial)

```
URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=12:antialias=true:hinting=true
URxvt*boldFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=12:antialias=true:hinting=true
```